# How to replace the text of a row with different text after the click of an image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So this is only part of my code, I have a function that changes the larger picture to the full sized files of the thumbnails when they are clicked. However, I am having trouble with how to replace the words in the 
last part of it id="final". So If I click the first image the "sometext" changes to a description about the picture clicked so forth and so forth.

```
<tr id="photos">
    <td><img id="tests" src="examt-nail.jpg" alt="thumbnail" onclick="ChangeImage('exam.jpg');"></td>
    <td><img id="true" src="kimt-nail.jpg" alt="thumbnail" onclick="ChangeImage('kim.jpg');"></td>
    <td><img id="hate" src="codingt-nail.jpg" alt="thumbnail" onclick="ChangeImage('coding.jpg');"></td>
    <td><img id="yellow" src="spongebobt-nail.jpg" alt="thumbnail" onclick="ChangeImage('bob.jpg');"></td>
    <td><img id="help" src="helpt-nail.png" alt="thumbnail" onclick="ChangeImage('help.png');"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr" id="name">
    <td colspan="5"><img id="me" src="mestretch.jpg" alt="thumbnail" height="750px" width="750px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5" id="final">sometext</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the text of an element you can use the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('final');
elem.textContent = "New Text";
```

You shouldn't use `innerHTML` when only the text changes.

Comment: Then I need more information about what you are trying to do.

Comment: So basically, I am trying to change the text of the cell with the id="final" whenever I click on an image. I have 5 thumbnails and 1 full sized image, whenever I click the thumbnail the larger image changes to that of the thumbnail (only larger) so along with that change I need the text in "final" to change to a description of the image that is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ChangeImage(img, desc){
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = desc;

}
```

```html
<td><img id="tests" src="examt-nail.jpg" alt="thumbnail" onclick="ChangeImage('exam.jpg', 'Exam Description');">
</td>
<div id="final">sometext</div>
```

Inside your `ChangeImage()` function at the end add this code to change the text inside your div.

```
document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "Your text";
```

You can also make this text variable by passing it as argument in ChangeImage() function while calling it.

```
<td><img id="tests" src="examt-nail.jpg" alt="thumbnail" onclick="ChangeImage('exam.jpg', 'Exam Description');"></td>
```

Inside Js code modify your function as:

```
function ChangeImage(img, desc){
    //your code

    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = desc;

}
```